# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "jna.boot.library.path" "read")

Tags: java, security, sandbox, access-control, accesscontrolexception

I am having some trouble running my signed web applet,

it runs fine within Eclipse, but as soon as I upload to the webpage, I get this error log:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.dermalog.imaging.capturing.cwrap.vc.DermalogvcLibrary.<clinit>(DermalogvcLibrary.java:30)
at com.dermalog.imaging.capturing.DeviceManager.<clinit>(DeviceManager.java:33)
at MyPackage.Bio.GetDevice(Bio.java:218)
at MyPackage.Bio.StartDevice(Bio.java:150)
at MyPackage.Bio.access$0(Bio.java:144)
at MyPackage.Bio$1.run(Bio.java:80)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at MyPackage.Bio.<init>(Bio.java:76)
at MyPackage.Test$2.actionPerformed(Test.java:45)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied("java.util.PropertyPermission" "jna.boot.library.path" "read")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeLibrary(Native.java:650)
at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:109)
... 44 more
```

I believe this is a problem with breaking out of the sandbox, and communicating with the computer.

Can using **AccessController.doPrivileged** solve the problem? What are my options other than modifying the policy file?

Comment: *"Can using AccessController.doPrivileged solve the problem?"*  Possibly, but only if it is a trusted applet whose methods are being called from JS.  Otherwise it should be trusted as soon as the user OKs the trust prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, the problem I had, was that my referenced Jar files (outside the main Jar) was not signed, and after signing them the problem went away.